# Did anyone in England in the 1680's wear a beard?

Tags: england, 17th-century, fashion

I'm trying to find any examples of beards in England during the 1680s.
I know they weren't popular but that doesn't mean they didn't exist at all.
A picture would be ideal, although I appreciate this is unlikely!

Comment: This chap? https://www.npg.org.uk/collections/search/portraitExtended/mw69740/Egbert-van-Heemskerck-the-Elder

Comment: [van Dyk](https://www.google.com/search?q=men+1680...1690&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwin44C9oe3nAhVll-AKHaZzAqcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=men+1680...1690&gs_l=img.3...2728.2728..3331...0.0..0.93.93.1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.tDcrg-MZ2Qs&ei=311VXuf3EOWuggem54m4Cg&bih=690&biw=1391&safe=active#imgrc=-FLlwl7MSVYLCM)  I did a google image search on Men, England 1680...1690 and found a few.

Comment: Wait a bit. In print: Alun Withey: "Concerning Beards: Facial Hair, Health and Practice in England, 1650–1900", 2020.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1689 [Solomon Ayllon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Ayllon) was appointed rabbi of the Spanish and Portuguese Jews in London, and as you can see in the picture on Wikipedia, he wore a beard.

(His predecessor, [Jacob Abendana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Abendana), who was appointed in 1680, probably did too - most religious Jews, or at least rabbis, at that time did - but I don't know of any picture of him.)

Comment: Kudo's for a good catch.  Framing the problem is half the battle. +1

Comment: That's great information. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, people would have worn beards in 17th century England for religious or similar reasons.

Comment: Too bad [Anthony van Dyck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_van_Dyck) died a generation earlier in 1641. [Self portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_van_Dyck#/media/File:Anthonyvandyckselfportrait.jpeg)

Comment: Does it count if the people noted as wearing beards at the time weren't there legally?

Comment: @user6591, once Cromwell (and afterwards Charles II) decided not to enforce the edict of expulsion of 1290, it was a dead letter, and the Jews' presence in England was at least legally tolerated.